# Render Thread API Issues

Tags: multithreading, winapi, opengl, graphics, directx

Listed below are some API issues I expect to encounter when adding a render thread to code so that all graphics API calls that used to all occur on the main thread now occur on a dedicated background thread.

For Direct3D and OpenGL on Win32, are there additional issues that are involved that I'm not aware of, or has my list covered it?

List of expected issues:

- D3D9: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb147224%28v=vs.85%29.aspx . This basically means allowance has to be made for particular special operations to occur on the main thread with D3D9.
- D3D10+: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee417025.aspx#Multithreading_and_DXGI . This basically means that the main thread (with the message pump) shouldn't block waiting on the render thread (specifically, for the render thread to make DXGI calls).
- OpenGL: no issues so long as the context is only active on the render thread, but as above some care during mode changes, etc.

Note: assume my application has been careful to store and isolate all of the data the render thread will require to complete its processing, such as input buffer data, etc. I am asking specifically about window system and API-level issues and any gotchas.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it requires answerers to be clairvoyant.

Comment: There's no clairvoyance involved, so far as I can tell. The graphics and windowing API requirements involved for the situation described are application-independent and possible to enumerate if you know what they are. The question is, have I listed all of the API-level issues I need to be aware of specifically for the case where graphics API calls (and just those) are shifted to a background thread?

Comment: If you use GLFW for OpenGL there's not much to worry about except calling from the same thread as the context. Also attach a debuglog function to OpenGL if you are running a profile that supports it.